# Entity framework methods called in web layer need a reference from data layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, layer

I have entity framework entities and methods in proxy class in the data layer `dats.dll`.

In the business layer `bll.dll`, I am referencing `dats.dll` and wrapping the data layer methods.

But, when I call the methods in `bll.dll` in the aspx page, Visual Studio (C#) is complaining about adding a reference to `dats.dll`

Why should I add a reference to the `dats.dll` when it is already added to `bll.dll`.

I am referencing `bll.dll` in the aspx project (Presentation layer)

Thanks for a quick reply

Answer (score 2):

I guess your Business layer methods are returning the entities or Collection of Entities(The Entity classes created by Entity framework, Which is present in your data project). You may either create your simple DTO's/POCO's as needed and map your Entities to your DTO/POCO in your BL layer and returns that.

So your solution will have 4 projects

- **Data** Project : Entites created by EF ( Customer,Product etc) & Data access classes/methods.
- **DTO**   Project : Your DTO/POCO classes which is being used across multiple
  projects.
- **BL** Project  :  Your BL Methods which calls methods in your
  Data project , Map those responses to your DTO's ( You may use
  Automapper library for mapping or manually map each property)
- **Web Project** : Your Web app project. you need to add 2 project references
  to this. 1) Your BL Project 2) Your DTO project.

With this approach, You do not need a reference to your data project in your Web Project.